# What m_pMainWnd pointer points to by default?

Tags: c++, pointers, mfc

I'm currently studying MFC library and I noticed that in default generated application by Visual Studio there is no assignment to m_pMainWnd pointer. So my question is what that pointer points to? I also did an example from a tutorial I found recently and there was a dialog class object created in InitInstance function and it's address was assigned to m_pMainWnd pointer:

```
virtual BOOL InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    GAME_FORM dlg; //dialog object
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg; //dialog object set as main window
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
}
```

When MFC application is created by application wizard there are only two lines in entire solution where m_pMainWnd is used, and it's not an asiggement. So what that pointer points to?

```
BOOL CMFCTestyApp::InitInstance()
{
(...)
// The one and only window has been initialized, so show and update it
m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
(...)
}
```

Comment: Your App class inherits from many layers of base classes. They also have tons of code in them, to set up the environment for running the app code.

Comment: You won't be able to understand MFC, unless you are intimately familiar with the Windows API (and C++). If you really want to get started with Windows programming, start with [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx).

Comment: `m_pMainWnd` is `NULL` by default. You have to tell MFC that in this case `dlg` is used as your main window. Some MFC classes need to know where the main windows is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It initially is NULL.  The default constructor for `CWinThread` (`CWinApp` is derived from `CWinThread`) calls `CWinThread::CommonConstruct()`.  `CWinThread::CommonConstruct()` sets

`m_pMainWnd = NULL;`

If you have an wizard generated SDI program, the main window will later be initialized in CSingleDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile().  The stack trace will look something like this:

```
    mfc120ud.dll!CSingleDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile(const wchar_t * lpszPathName, int bAddToMRU, int bMakeVisible) Line 205   C++
    mfc120ud.dll!CSingleDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile(const wchar_t * lpszPathName, int bMakeVisible) Line 83   C++
    mfc120ud.dll!CDocManager::OnFileNew() Line 912  C++
    mfc120ud.dll!CWinApp::OnFileNew() Line 21   C++
    mfc120ud.dll!_AfxDispatchCmdMsg(CCmdTarget * pTarget, unsigned int nID, int nCode, void (void) * pfn, void * pExtra, unsigned int nSig, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo) Line 77  C++
    mfc120ud.dll!CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID, int nCode, void * pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo) Line 373   C++
    mfc120ud.dll!CWinApp::ProcessShellCommand(CCommandLineInfo & rCmdInfo) Line 35  C++
    ModelessTest.exe!CModelessTestApp::InitInstance() Line 133  C++
```

All the source code for MFC comes with Visual C++.  You can step through it yourself to see when a variable changes or set a breakpoint to see when a memory location changes.

If you have an MDI application, you have to explicitly create the MDI frame window in your overloaded CWinApp::InitInstance() function and then manually set the m_pMainWnd pointer to the MDI frame window.  If you use a wizard to generate the application, it will set that up for you.